# Symfony: Inject object (not service) to service constructor

Tags: symfony

In the definition of my services, I'd like to pass as a service argument constructor an object not a service.

From config.yml:

```
services:
  acme.services.exampleservice:
    class:  Acme\ExampleBundle\Services\ExampleService
    arguments: 
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        httpClient: \Example\Http\Client\Client
```

Note the `httpClient` argument. This must be an instance of the `\Example\Http\Client\Client` class.

The above does not work - the string "\Example\Http\Client\Client" is passed as the `httpClient` argument to the service.

What is the syntax for achieving the above by means of passing an instance of `\Example\Http\Client\Client` to the service constructor?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a private service. Here's what's written in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html):

> If you use a private service as an argument to more than one other service, this will result in two different instances being used as the instantiation of the private service is done inline (e.g. new PrivateFooBar()).

```
services:
  acme.services.exampleservice:
    class:  Acme\ExampleBundle\Services\ExampleService
    arguments: 
        entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        httpClient: acme.services.httpClient

  acme.services.httpClient:
    class: Example\Http\Client\Client
    public: false
```

You will not be able to retrieve a private service from the container. From the outside it looks just as if you passed a regular object to the constructor of your service.