# Symfony config.yml - How to pass constructor arguments by name?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I am trying to use a custom formatter for log entries created with Monlog in my Symfony WebApp:

```
//config.yml
services:
    monolog.formatter.extended:
        class: Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter
        arguments:
            format: "[%%datetime%%] %%channel%%.%%level_name%% ...\n\n"
            allowInlineLineBreaks: true
            ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra: true
        calls:
            - [includeStacktraces]
```

All log entries created with this formatter start with `[1]...` instead of inserting the correct timestamp like `[2015-12-16 10:40:23]...`

This problem does not show up when I remove the two additional paramters `allowInlineLineBreaks` and `ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra`:

```
arguments:
    format: "[%%datetime%%] %%channel%%.%%level_name%% ...\n\n"
```

However everything works fine when I do not pass the arguments by name but simply as complete list. The `LineFormatter` constructor looks like this:

```
public function __construct($format = null, $dateFormat = null, $allowInlineLineBreaks = false, $ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra = false) { ...}
```

So adding the arguments as list workes fine:

```
 arguments:
    - "[%%datetime%%] %%channel%%.%%level_name%% ...\n\n"
    - null
    - true
    - true
```

What is wrong with passing the arguments by name? I have seen this in several examples but obvious there is something wrong in the way I use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I never saw injecting arguments using keys.
I know you can use keys when dealing with parameters or when injecting using setters, like the documentation says:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection

If you want to inject using setters you could do:

```
//config.yml
services:
    some.service.name:
        class: SomeClass
        calls:
            - [setFormat, "[%%datetime%%] %%channel%%.%%level_name%%"]
```

But the Monolog LineFormatter doesn't support that.

In the end I think you will go for the common array mode.

I hope this helps, if you have some docs showing examples using keys I would like to see that and then we can discuss it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I saw this arguments-by-name style in different examples (e.g. http://www.petethompson.net/blog/symfony/2015/03/15/symfony-logging-client-ip/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11654384/777861) and thought it would valid syntax. But your are right, I cannot find any documentation that uses this style. Strange.

Comment: Seems like the dependency injector is considering only the values, so if you use the name and keep the order its ok, but if you try to change the order it will also inject in a wrong order. I was also looking into some internals and seems like the key is only used to replace arguments in case you need.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this makes complete sense. Since the dateFormat is the second argument it is obvious that this cannot work out when "true" (or something else not being a valid) is passed as second argument, no matte what name was used.